# get user name who has same project with user logged in

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

how can I get Username who has same project with user logged in. Use Laravel and many to many relation. Table Pivot user_projects has user_id and project_id.

**this my controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('projects')->get();
        return view ('teams.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

**this my view index**

```
<table class="table table-consended">
   <tr>
      <th> <h4>No</h4> </th>
      <th> <h4>Name</h4> </th>
      <th> <h4>Role</h4> </th>
      <th> <h4>Project</h4> </th>
   </tr>
      @foreach($users as $item => $user)                        
   <tr>
      <td>{{$item+1}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
      <td>
      @foreach ($user->projects as $project)
        {{$project->project_name}}
      @endforeach
       </td>
    </tr>
       @endforeach()
 </table>
```

[image: data table]

[image: view index]

[image: my final view index]

[image: data]

but when the project not added, the view is blank.

Comment: use `->whereHas('projects', function($q){ $q->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id); })`

Comment: in my controller? after `with('projects')` ?

Comment: `$users = User::whereHas('projects', function($q){ $q->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id); })>get();`

Comment: it just display user and his project, not display user who has same project

Comment: could you please explain with some sample data?

Comment: see my edit in question

Comment: and what your final result? you want to fetch user associate with projects id 3? or something else?

Comment: i want to like mockups

Comment: then this should give you that `$users = User::whereHas('projects', function($q){ $q->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id); })>get();`

Comment: when I try, the data like in the question,